# quick regex, match with a character but not including that character

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match from the character P all of the charters after P and between a newline character.

What I have tried is "P.*\n" which obviously still matches P, but I want all the characters after p and before a newline character.

Anyone know?

Comment: You mean something like `en` in `pen\n`?

Comment: yes, or "G99 P blahblah.blah \n" I want " blahblah.blah "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
(?<=P).*(?!\n)
```

Positive lookbehind for the P, then negative lookahead for the newline.

Edited my original answer.

Comment: By default, dot (`.`) doesn't match newline. So, using just `(?<=P).*` will work.

Answer (score 2):

just use:

```
p(.*)
```

make sure you are not using the "multiline" regex option.

Comment: +1 .. the dot actually means "anything that isn't a newline". Can't believe I didn't remember that myself :(

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
P(.*?)\n
```

The characters you want are in group 1

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
P(.*?)\n
```

[image]

From Regex hero