# Matching the character but not including that character and everything after

Tags: javascript, regex

Before anyone says it's duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090734/quick-regex-match-with-a-character-but-not-including-that-character) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687438/capture-string-to-a-character-but-not-including-the-character). `JavaScript` doesn't have `look behind` so I've been struggling with this. It does have `look ahead` as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead)

What I really want to do is this. I have :-
`hey:blah,{'some':'obj','another':[4,5,0]}`

I want to extract everything after but not including the first `:`.
So my output would be:-
`blah,{'some':'obj','another':[4,5,0]}`

My attempt so far:-
`(:.+) //gives :blah,{'some':'obj','another':[4,5,0]}` - note that it has `:`
`[^\w:].+ //gives ,{'some':'obj','another':[4,5,0]}` - not the result I expected. `blah` is missing.

I'm trying to do this in pure regex and trying to avoid looping or any string manipulation of that sort.
My attempt has been to no avail so far.

Comment: Use capturing group.

Comment: Why are you using regexps to manipulate string representation of a not-quite-valid JS object? What are you going to do with the even-less-valid JS "object" resulting from your regexp? Remember that regexps by themselves don't **do** anything; they just **match**. They don't "extract" anything, they just **match**. To do anything with that match, or even invoke it, you're going to have to engage in JavaScript "trickery", be it as simple as a call to `String#match`. As long as you're doing that, why does it offend your sensibilities to throw in a `split`, or a `replace`, or a `slice`?

Comment: I don't know why you would think that looping might be required; it's not. As for "string manipulation", regexps already are "string manipulators", so you're manipulating the string anyway.

Comment: @torazaburo I understand they just **match** but shouldn't it be able to **match** and return the matched string? Also, please let's not go to the implementation details regardless of valid or invalid JS object. And trust me, it doesn't offend me to use `javascript's` method or "trickery" as I called it before. I just wanted it to be done with as much regex as possible. I've mentioned already that I'm willing to accept JavaScript's "trickery" as well.

Comment: Regexps do not "return" anything. They exist in the context of a language, in which they are invoked by some API, such as in JS `String#match` or `RegExp.test`, and those APIs may return a boolean value saying whether a match occurred, and/or the string which matched and capturing groups if present. Any use of regexps in JS will require the use of an API. Therefore, I stand by my assertion that any use of regexps involves use of JS "trickery". It's hard to reconcile your statement that "you're willing to accept JS trickery" with your comment that "But I'm trying to do it with no trickery".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[^:]*:(.*$)
```

You can try this.Grab the group 1 .See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vH0iN5/1

Comment: @vks Actually it would be simpler to just say `/:(.*)/`. The `:` will match the first colon in the string anyway. The `.*` will match up to the end of the string anyway.

Comment: @shriek you need to grab `group 1` not the match.

Comment: @shriek vks is right. The regexr you provided works perfectly, matching the entire string. The first group matches the text the OP is looking for. This works perfectly in JS. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Ahh, I see. This might be the closest to what I'm looking for. If I understand correctly technically just `:(.*$)` would work too but yours just confirms that it has to start at the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

## RegExps

If you don't wish to have anything selected, you can wrap it in a look-ahed:

```
(?=:(.*))
```

---

If you want to go until the following colon:

```
(?=:([^:]*))
```

## JavaScript code

Because nothing is selected, `[0]` will be blank. Access `[1]`:

```
/(?=:(.*))/.exec("hey:blah,{'some':'obj','another':[4,5,0]}")[1];
//                         Use [1] not [0]                       ^^
```

That said, is there anything wrong with:

```
var str = "hey:blah,{'some':'obj','another':[4,5,0]}";
str.substr(str.indexOf(':') + 1);
```

Comment: Hmm.. I'm just getting `"blah,{'some'"` with your `exec` solution. And `indexOf` is also accepted but this would be the same answer as by [@Avinash Raj](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30950471/1204312) which uses JavaScript's methods. I would be inclined to mark this as correct but so would I with @Avinash's solution.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `string.replace`

```
string.replace(/^[^:]*:/, "");
```

Comment: That would be my second options, yes. But I'm trying to do it with no trickery from `javascript`.

Comment: If you want to do match then no other option than a capturing group.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I don't know why more people don't use `/^.*?:/`, to me it looks cleaner.

Comment: Because of the speed, check both the regex in regex101.com by clicking the debugger option.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Forgive my naivety on regex but did you mean [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-capturing-parentheses) when you say capturing group? 
@torazaburo "trickery" in a sense that if someone wants to use that regex in a language that doesn't have `replace` then s/he should be able to.

Comment: But I would mark this as the correct one if I find nothing else since I did tag this with `javascript`.